# Facebook PHP SDK fails on first page load

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

The FIRST time my index.php loads I get a value of 0 when calling:

```
$facebook->getUser();//returning 0 instead of id on first page load
```

The call works fine on any subsequent page load.

This is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $FB_APP_ID, 
        'secret' => $FB_APP_SECRET
    ));
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();//Returns 0 on first load.
```

Has anyone else experienced this? Maybe I should automatically reload the page if `$facebook->getUser();` does not return a valid user?

Comment: how about try catching?

Comment: I do catch the error, I don't show that for brevity.

Comment: Have you checked what getUser returns first?

Comment: Get user returns 0 (updated the question)

Comment: I tried checking for the error and then calling new Facebook() again, but it does not solve the issue, only a page reload seems to work.

Comment: Where are the callback url pointing to? Please Ensure the callback/redirect url you have provided correctly points to your php page.

Answer (score -1):

May be it is not authenticating it for very first time, You can do some thing like this:

```
<?php

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => xxx, 
        'secret' => xxx
    ));

    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $me = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $me['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll redirect and
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo("<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, redirect for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo("<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");

    }

  ?>
```

**EDIT:**

If error persists, try with this edit, just change your this line:

```
$me = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

to this:

```
$me= $facebook->api('/'.$user_id, 'GET');
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not help since user id is 0 :) $me= $facebook->api('/'.$user_id, 'GET');

Comment: And I don't want to send the user to a facebook login page because they may not be a facebook user to begin with.

Comment: But access token is only granted to facebook users!

Comment: Obviously non facebook users will not be using the facebook functionality of the page!